# "cannot insert null value to primary key" error while trying to insert a non-null value

Tags: c#, exception, ado.net, null, primary-key

i have a composite key(**col1, col2**) in my table
i get the "cannot insert null value to primary key" error on col1 but actually im not trying to insert null value, **i've checked in debug mode, the value is not null**
any ideas?

this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc1]
@col1 char(11) = NULL,
@col2 nchar(50) = NULL,
@col3 real = NULL
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
update dbo.table1 set col2 = @col2 where col1 = @col1 AND col3 = @col3
if @@ROWCOUNT=0
insert into dbo.table1 ( col1, col2, col3 ) values ( @col1, @col2, @col3 )
```

this is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = create_conn();
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("another_proc", conn);
command.Parameters.Add("col1", SqlDbType.Char).Value = col1;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

command = new SqlCommand("proc1", conn);

// here i set the value of the parameter
**command.Parameters.Add("col1", SqlDbType.Char).Value = col1;**

command.Parameters.Add("col2", SqlDbType.NChar);
command.Parameters.Add("col3", SqlDbType.Real);
double y, yk, ym, yy;
int k, m;
string col2;
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    col2 = dr["col2"].ToString().Trim();
    yk = Double.Parse(dr["yk"].ToString());
    ym = Double.Parse(dr["ym"].ToString());
    yy = Double.Parse(dr["yy"].ToString());
    k = Int32.Parse(dr["k"].ToString());
    m = Int32.Parse(dr["m"].ToString());
    y = Double.Parse(dr["y"].ToString());
    double col3 = ...some calculation here...;
    command.Parameters["col2"].Value = col2;
    command.Parameters["col3"].Value = col3;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

updated code:

```
SqlConnection conn = create_conn();
conn.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("another_proc", conn);
command.Parameters.Add("col1", SqlDbType.Char).Value = col1;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

command.CommandText = "proc1";
command.Parameters.Add("col2", SqlDbType.NChar);
command.Parameters.Add("col3", SqlDbType.Real);
double y, yk, ym, yy;
int k, m;
string col2;
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    col2 = dr["col2"].ToString().Trim();
    yk = Double.Parse(dr["yk"].ToString());
    ym = Double.Parse(dr["ym"].ToString());
    yy = Double.Parse(dr["yy"].ToString());
    k = Int32.Parse(dr["k"].ToString());
    m = Int32.Parse(dr["m"].ToString());
    y = Double.Parse(dr["y"].ToString());
    double col3 = k * (yk / 100) + m * (ym / 100) + y * (yy / 100);
    command.Parameters["col2"].Value = col2;
    command.Parameters["col3"].Value = col3;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Col1 and col2 should not be nullable as they are making composite key. 
Change

```
@col1 char(11) = NULL,
@col2 nchar(50) = NULL,
```

To

```
@col1 char(11) ,
@col2 nchar(50),
```

Also change the parameter addition for all parameters to sql procedure

```
command.Parameters.Add("col1", SqlDbType.Char).Value = col1;
```

To

```
command.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.Char).Value = col1;
```

or

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.Char);
 command.Parameters["@col1"].Value = col1;
```

**EDIT**

**The error "Procedure or function 'proc1' expects parameter '@col1', which was not supplied." you got was misleading**,  The problem was due to not setting of CommandType. Create new command and add the statement below before you execute command.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("proc1", conn);
command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Also clear the parameter collection in the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   col1 = "Col1 value " + i;
   col2 = "Col2 value " + i;
   col3 = "Col3 value" + i;

   command.Parameters.Clear();

   command.Parameters.Add("@col1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = col1;
   command.Parameters.Add("@col2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = col2;
   command.Parameters.Add("@col3", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = col3;

   command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: ive tried it. now it gives this error: "Procedure or function 'proc1' expects parameter '@col1', which was not supplied."

Comment: "Procedure or function 'proc1' expects parameter '@col1', which was not supplied."

Comment: Try this command.Parameters["col1"].Value = col2;command.Parameters["col2"].Value = col2;
 command.Parameters["col3"].Value = col3;

Comment: It might complain about @ col2 and @ Col3 if you remove the error of @ Col1. Please add @ at all places with col1, Col2, Col3

Comment: tried it. still saying **Procedure or function 'proc1' expects parameter '@col1', which was not supplied**. i always use column names without @. i dont think its relevant

Comment: I have traced out the problem and updated answer with working code, Tell me if you still have problem.

Comment: you said: "The problem was with using same command for two procedures and setting of CommandType." but it has nothing to do with using the same command for two procedures. it works now. **the only error source is command type**. thanks

Answer (score 2):

How did we all miss it?

```
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```